# $\prod_{I = 1}^N(x + y_i) = \prod_{I = 1}^N(x - y_i)^{\alpha_i}$ where all elements are non-zero natural numbers and $x > \forall y_i$ for any $x$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, products

I am interested if there are possible criteria one can place on the $y_i$'s which will give solutions to this relationship. The simplest way I can think of is to allow some positive integer $m_i, n_i$ where $x - y_i = n_i$ and $x + y_i = m_i$ allowing for $(x, y_i) = (\frac{m_i + n_i}{2}, \frac{m_i - n_i}{2})$ where $2x = m_i + n_i$ for all $i$. It is clear that when $GCD(2x, n_i) = d_i$, then $d_i|m_i$, but do all non trivial solutions require $GCD(2x, n_i) > 1$?

Comment: Are this finite products, infinite products, ...?

Comment: In this case, the index would be arbitrary, so I am not really sure how to answer your question. This was something I just thought about. I am trying to find solutions for any natural number $x$. More so, the conditions on the $y_i$'s in relation to $x$.

Comment: Supposed that there is one term in the product, then we have $A=\left(1+\frac{y_1}{x}\right)=x^{\alpha_1-1}\left(1-\frac{y_1}{x}\right)^{\alpha_1}=x^{\alpha_1-1} B^{\alpha_1}$. Since $0<B<1<A$, $x$ must be bigger than 1 and $\alpha_1$ must be bigger than 1.

Comment: @GregMartin The terms on the left hand side are positive integers, so an infinite product of them diverges.

Comment: @jmath What do you mean by *"...and $x>\forall y_i$ for any $x$"*? There is only one $x$ in the expression, and do you mean that it should be, greater than all $y_i$? And can you confirm that the products should be finite, or explain how the infinite case makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one term in the product, it becomes
$$x+y=(x-y)^{\alpha}.\tag{1}$$
Set $u:=x+y$ and $v:=x-y$ so that $u\equiv v\pmod{2}$ and $u>v$. We recover $x$ and $y$ by $x=\tfrac{u+v}{2}$ and $y:=\tfrac{u-v}{2}$. Then the above becomes
$$u=v^{\alpha},$$
where clearly $u\equiv v\pmod{2}$, and we have $u>v$ if and only if $v,\alpha>1$. This shows that all solutions to $(1)$ are given by
$$(x,y,\alpha)=\left(\frac{v^{\alpha}+v}{2},\frac{v^{\alpha}-v}{2},\alpha\right),\qquad v,\alpha>1.$$

Comment: So does that mean when there are more terms, all solutions must be of that form? For instance, $u_i = x + y_i$, and $v_i = x - y_i$ where $u_i \equiv v_i (\mod 2)$. Giving $(x, y_i, \alpha_i) = (\frac{v^{\alpha_i} + v}{2}, \frac{v^{\alpha_i} - v}{2}, \alpha_i)$?